# Using 2 primary partitions on a hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I would like to install 2 Operating Systems (one Windows and one Kali Linux) on 1 hard drive. It's easy to install both on a primary partition but I would like to put them into 2 different primary partition. Currently my hard drive has only 1 primary partition (currently installed with Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit). So I have to create the other primary partition for Kali Linux. As far as I know there should be only 1 primary partition **active** at a time. So I wonder what exactly **active** means here? Does that mean once booted from this partition, I cannot access to the other partition (to read/open files, ...)? I hope it's just some kind of flag indicating that it's the partition from which the currently loaded OS was booted.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Active" simply means that that is the partition on which your BIOS (firmware) will look for the first OS boot file - for Windows 7 that is BootMgr.exe.

(
Actually it is a little  more complicated. The BIOS *always* loads the master boot record from the drive that you've configured it to boot from in the "BIOS settings". The MBR is always sector 0 and is not part of any "file system". The MBR contains the table of primary partitions - maximum of four - and a tiny amount of code (440 bytes). One of the partitions is tagged as "active" in the partition table. The code from the MBR loads the first block of the active partition (also not part of any file system), which is called the "volume boot record". The code from the first block of the VBR reads the remainder of the VBR; it can be multiple blocks. This in turn has enough code to find and read an executable file from the root directory of the partition it's on, and transfer control to it. For a Windows Vista or later partition this is BootMgr.Exe, for earlier versions it was NTLDR.

Different OSs require different VBR contents. Different file systems do, too - the Windows VBR for a FAT32 partition is different from the one for an NTFS partition, because the code in the VBR has to understand enough of the file system structure to read that first OS boot file. That file in turn knows enough to read directories, etc.
)

In Windows, the Boot Configuration Database (BCD) is also on the active partition. The actual OS can be on another partition, and usually is.

If you use a multi-OS boot loader such as GRUB (as I expect you will) you want that on the active partition. It does not mean that that is the only partition accessible.

Answer (score 0):

A hard drive can only have up to 4 partitions. These 4 partitions are called *primary partitions*. To overcome this limitation, people invented *extended partitions*. An extended partition can consist of several *logical partitions*, thus allowing for more than 4 partitions.

The active partition is the primary partition that the BIOS chooses to boot from. If you'd like to dual-boot Kali Linux and Windows, you should set Kali Linux as the primary partition. Kali Linux should come with GRUB. GRUB presents an option menu when the computer boots. Using the option menu, you can choose whether to boot Kali Linux or Windows.

Accessing other partitions does not depend on which one is active. From Kali Linux you should be able to access the Windows partition. From Windows you'll need special software to access the Linux partition, since Windows does not understand Linux partitions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It's helpful but I could only accept the best (to me). I'll come back and vote this up once I have enough reputation.

Comment: No. A harddrive can have hundred of partitions. It is just that if you use one specific format (MBR) that you are limited to four primary partitions.  (Or up to 3 primary and one extended).  There is nothing in the drive itself which limits this, and there are many other partition schemes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what you want is:

1) If windows is already installed shrink the partition with GParted and leave the rest of the hard drive empty. (If windows isn't already installed don't let it patition the whole drive to begin with.)

2) Install linux and tell it to leave your existing partition alone. It will partition the rest of the drive and you won't have to worry about the details.